# Which Class Abc's object use less memory: a Class Abc or a Class Abc which also implements multiple interfaces (like Serializable etc)?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

We are in middle of optimizing memory usage of a massively multithreaded Java application.

I ran into above question when I saw few classes unnecessarily implementing interfaces which is are not required.

Though my gut says the Class object without any implementation should take lesser memory. But, I don't have anything to back that up.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're talking about Class instances, then yes, a Class implementing more interfaces would use (slightly) more memory than the same class not implementing as many interfaces. I suspect, though, that you're asking about objects that are instances of the given class. Those wouldn't be affected by the number of implemented interfaces. Implemented interfaces would only affect the aforementioned Class instances, not instances of a class.